# Compare MySQL and Cassandra?

Tags: database

I am trying to test a migration of data from a mySQL database to a Cassandra database.

What would be a good approach to do that and is there any tool to make my life easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a difficult problem, as long as you have an OLEDB or ADO.net connector to both your database and Cassandra, then you can write queries on both your source (mySQL) and your target (Cassandra using e.g. [Intellisoft's Oledb provider](http://www.pgoledb.com/index.php/purchase/pgnprcs-detail)).

Then you can pull data into a database technology of your choice.

Then you will need to use either

- a data comparison tool (like [Redgate Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/)) or,
- write your own using a customer written data comparison. Personally, I have created hashes of the keys and data for very comparison then compared the hashes.

Note: I do not work for, or am connected with Intellisoft or Redgate.

Answer (score 1):

This question is way bigger than a simple Q & A format.

You're asking the equivalent of asking a question like "I'm moving all my data from Excel to a database, what do I need to do?"  In other words, this isn't a simple migration, you're completely changing the underlying datastore.

You'll likely have to work closely with your data folks to figure out what their plan is, how they're going to juggle relationships, data types, etc, and then you can start figuring out what you'll need to do to validate . . .